# Internal Server Error and Machine Readable Names

Tags: 8, entities, debugging

I have installed a new local site using Drupal 8.1.10 which takes a lot of time whenever I give any command (lets say create a text field) and then sometimes it gives a 'Internal Server Error' after which the 'machine readable name' of the text field which I was creating becomes unusable.

It then gives the error 'The machine-readable name is already in use. It must be unique.' whereas the field was not created and the 'machine readable name' is not actually in use.

This has happened multiple times. How do I resolve this?

Answer (score -1):

Just try this :
on **.htaccess**, replace `Options +FollowSymLinks` by `Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch`

Example from : http://www.drupal8.ovh/en/tutoriels/9/install-drupal-8-virtualmin-error-500

Comment: Can you expand on why there is a symlink problem here?